# Grouping Adjacent Tiles

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

### Intro

Simplifed question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174267/two-dimensional-array-neighbour-cell-search

Hello all I am using Unity 5 to re-create the Puzzle Pirates Swordfight.  Its a copy, I am not planning to release it or use it, I am just practicing my algorithm and coding skills yet I have come up to a bottleneck.  I am coding in C# and open to any suggestions on the subject below. Thanks <3

This is my project demonstration

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRvGIDaY-aE

And this is the original one

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuy1Zqkjhn8

### Question

In a "grid[6,13]" there are 4 different colors of boxes.  I need an algorithm of which groups them minimum 2 wide and 2 tall, 2x2.  And thus always grouping them NxM.  My algorithm can group them 2x2 at the moment but this is so limiting.

### Situation

I created the exact copy of the Puzzle Pirates Swordfight board game screen with panels and images.

- Random color piece spawn and nextpiece spawn
- The free-fall of that piece and placing to the bottom.
- Controls such as; rotation and movement between the borders and avoiding the already placed pieces.  So a board can be full and Game Over by controlling the pieces to the sideways, but I want these already placed pieces to group up and form bigger pieces, called Gems.

Below is my algorithm.  It checks if the position is full.  It can be full with pieces CurrentPiece, RedPiece, RedGem or RedBreaker. the colors can change between Red Green Yellow Blue.  What it basically does is checks diagonally, not ortogonally; the following pieces are the same color or not. Then it deletes them if they are same color and creates a bigger one in their place.

- Puzzle Pirates Swordfight
- Super Puzzle Fighter Turbo 2
- Lumines

### Code

```
for (int y = 0; y < height-1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width-1; x++) {
            if (grid [x, y] != null) {
                if (grid [x, y].parent.name != "CurrentPiece" && grid [x,y].name.Contains("Piece")) {
                    string colorofpiece = grid [x, y].name.Substring (0, grid [x, y].name.IndexOf ("Piece"));
                    if ((grid [x + 1, y] != null && grid [x + 1, y].parent.name != "CurrentPiece" && grid [x + 1, y].name.Contains (colorofpiece + "Piece")) &&
                        (grid [x, y + 1] != null && grid [x, y + 1].parent.name != "CurrentPiece" && grid [x, y + 1].name.Contains (colorofpiece + "Piece")) &&
                        (grid [x + 1, y + 1] != null && grid [x + 1, y + 1].parent.name != "CurrentPiece" && grid [x + 1, y + 1].name.Contains (colorofpiece + "Piece"))) {

                        int colornumber = getColor (colorofpiece);

                        GameObject gem = Instantiate (GemPrefab, transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                        gem.name = colorofpiece + "Gem";
                        gem.transform.SetParent (grid [x, y].parent);
                        gem.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                        gem.transform.localPosition = grid [x, y].localPosition;
                        gem.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sprites [colornumber];
                        gem.transform.FindChild ("Breaker").GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sprites [colornumber + 1];
                        gem.transform.FindChild ("Breaker").transform.FindChild ("Border").GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sprites [colornumber + 2];

                        for (int j = y; j < y + 2; j++) {
                            for (int i = x; i < x + 2; i++) {
                                Destroy (grid [i, j].gameObject);
                                grid [i, j] = gem.GetComponent<Transform> ();
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```